# scroll view inside scroll layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollbar, scrollview

[image]

i need your help. Basically I created a  scrollView as a parent layout of an activity . Now i need to add many widgets inside the activity including an edittext containing large text values set inside this  edittext which is also scrollable , but my text inside an edit text not scrolling smoothly? i need text area like widgets , my xml code shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#498BF4"> 
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Registration"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:textSize="20dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>

  <ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scroll" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >  
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="User_id:*"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="40dip" 
    android:id="@+id/user">  
    </EditText>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="FirstName:*"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="40dip" 
    android:id="@+id/fname">  
    </EditText>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="LastName:*"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="40dip" 
    android:id="@+id/lname">  
    </EditText>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Email:*"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="40dip" 
    android:id="@+id/email">  
    </EditText>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Currency:*"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
    <Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="40dip">
    </Spinner>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Date of Birth:*"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="40dip" 
    android:id="@+id/dob">  
    </EditText>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/agepermission"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:visibility="gone"> 
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="150dip" 
    android:id="@+id/ageterms"

    android:maxLines="10"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    >  
    </EditText>
    <CheckBox 
    android:text="I have permission to use the  website from parent/guardian.*" 
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </CheckBox>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Parent Name:*"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="40dip" 
    android:id="@+id/pname">  
    </EditText>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Parent Email:*"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="40dip" 
    android:id="@+id/pemail">  
    </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Terms and conditions:*"
    android:textSize="15dip"/>

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="200dip" 
    android:id="@+id/terms"
   ![android:text="i need your help. Basically I created a scrollView as a parent layout of an activity . Now i need to add many widgets inside the activity including an edittext containing large text values set inside this edittext which is also scrollable , but my text inside an edit text not scrolling smoothly? i need text area like widgets i need your help. Basically I created a scrollView as a parent layout of an activity . Now i need to add many widgets inside the activity including an edittext containing large text values set inside this edittext which is also scrollable , but my text inside an edit text not scrolling smoothly? i need text area like widgets i need your help. Basically I created a scrollView as a parent layout of an activity . Now i need to add many widgets inside the activity including an edittext containing large text values set inside this edittext which is also scrollable , but my text inside an edit text not scrolling smoothly? i need text area like widgets i need your help. Basically I created a scrollView as a parent layout of an activity . Now i need to add many widgets inside the activity including an edittext containing large text values set inside this edittext which is also scrollable , but my text inside an edit text not scrolling smoothly? i need text area like widgets"][2]
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    >  
    </EditText>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="By clicking on 'Sign Up' button below you are agreeing to the Terms of Service above and both the Program Policy and the Privacy Policy."
    android:textSize="15dip"/>
    <Button 
    android:text="Sign Up" 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    >
    </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: plz elaborate ur question is very unclear...

Comment: Just put your screenshot that you want. And we will help you more properly. Also try to put the xml code that you are using.

Comment: what you want to do ? If you want to scroll the text inside the Edittext then make the height of the Edittext that allow multiline and to see and then try it.

Comment: I have the same problem: A EditText with android:scrollbars="vertical", which is inside a layout (the form) that itself is scrollable. Now, the outer scrollable grabs the scroll gesture when trying to scroll in the EditText. If the gesture happens inside the EditText, the EditText should be scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

use below tag in your edittext , if it input is multiline

```
   android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem here.

So far I know the only solution is to disable the scrolling of the ScrollView when the EditText got focus.